# Assign id dynamically for more than one tag

Tags: jquery

I'm using following code to assign id of input tag when they are cloned.Is it possible to use same find method to select more tags like tr textarea etc.

```
      var i=1;
      $("#bt1").click(function() {
       $("#invoice_tab tr:nth-child(2)").clone().find("input").each(function() {
           $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
            'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
            'value': ''               
           });
       }).end().appendTo("#invoice_tab");
       i++;
```

Comment: If you are not actually going to use the id values, then you could just remove them from the cloned entries rather than assign new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use same find method to select more tags like tr textarea etc.

Yes... You can try it yourself...

```
 var i=1;
  $("#bt1").click(function() {
   $("#invoice_tab tr:nth-child(2)").clone().find("input, textarea, tr").each(function() {
       $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
        'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
        'value': ''               
       });
   }).end().appendTo("#invoice_tab");
   i++;
```

Just make sure the `id` remain **unique**. There can not be more then one element in the page-DOM with the same `id` value.